# how to create directory in docker from terminal from zsh terminal?

Tags: macos, docker, dockerfile, zsh

so i have downloaded `Docker Desktop` and until now i have tested out containers and stuff just executing regular commands (docker ps, docker images..., docker run...) inside my zsh terminal and it works fine but now i am in a position where i want to create a directory inside docker host so that i can put my `dockerfile` inside, but if i run `mkdir directory-name` it is going to create the directory inside my mac not docker! so what command can i use to indicate that i want the directory to be created on docker not on my own mac machine?

[image]

Comment: you do all that inside the dockerfile

Comment: @drum what do you mean? i want to create a directory to put the dockerfile inside!

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to create a directory "inside Docker"; you'd create your application source code on the host system as normal, write a `Dockerfile` to package it into an image, and run `docker build` to create the Docker image.  The Docker documentation includes a [tutorial series](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) that could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

While your docker container is running, you can start a new shell session inside using [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

```sh
docker exec -it mycontainer bash
```

- `-i` means interactive - so you can type
- `-t` allocates a pseudo-TTY - just know that you need the argument

Then inside this bash, you can create folders and files all you want and they will be placed inside your running container. Note that whenever you remove the container (e.g. to update its image), these changes will be **entirely lost**. For persistence, use [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── simple-web-app
```

Your Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch

ADD simple-web-app simple-web-app
```

Then you would run

```
docker build .
```